Design the self driving robot and implement it into Gazebo to check out
I don't know how to design my self-driving delivery robot, just need to do it fast and reliable through fixing problems,and then make the physical form of it.Have to design the robot from sketch and implement it into Gazebo, But I have no idea how can I do it...within not having any skills of drawing and so on? I don't want to just give up because I don't know how to draw and implement it, please guide me through it If you are aware of it,please
I tried Fusion 360 and Autocad,Gazebo,ROS

This is way to broad for anyone to realistically answer on SO. The best advice would be to read through the move_it docs
